# Should we use [had been walking] or [had walking] in particular sentence

Tags: grammar, differences, passive-voice, perfect-aspect

***My hair was wet. I ______ in the rain.***
Which should I put in ? [had been walking] or [had walking] and why ?
just I don't see any differences between both options.

Comment: *Had walking* is wrong in this construction. But you could used *had walked* without a problem.

Comment: The difference between the options is that one is English and the other is gibberish. _Had walking_ does not exist as a verbal construction in English in any context at all. This is very basic English morphology which can be looked up in any basic English grammar.

Comment: Ditto.  But you might be able to use "***was*** walking, especially if you switch the order of the sentences ("I was walking in the rain. My hair was wet.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible form is 'had been walking'. It is Past Perfect Continuous Tense, which is used to describe a process completed or not completed before a certain past moment. The result of this process is in the first sentence / 'wet hair'/.
The other form /had walking/ is grammatically wrong.